# Wrong results with CUDA threads writing on private locations in global memory

Tags: c++, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu, gpgpu

**EDIT 3:** 
I need each thread to write and read a private location in global memory. Below I post a working code showing my problem. In the following, I'll list the main variables and structures involved.

**Variables**:

- `srcArr_h` (host) --> `srcArr_d` (device) : array of random floats in the range [0, `COLORLEVELS`] with dimensions given by `ARRDIM`
- `auxD` (device) : array of dimension `ARRDIM` * `ARRDIM` holding the final result in device
- `auxH` (host) : array of dimension `ARRDIM` * `ARRDIM` holding the final result in host
- `c_glob_d` (device) : array that reserves a private location of `COLORLEVELS` floats for each thread, with size given by `num_threads` * `COLORLEVELS`
- `idx` (device) : identification number of current thread

**My problem**: in the kernel, I update `c_glob[idx]` for each value `ic` (`ic`∈ [0, `COLORLEVELS`]), i.e. `c_glob[idx][ic]`. I use  `c_glob[idx][COLORLEVELS]` to compute the final result `g0` stored in `auxD`. My problem is that my final results are wrong. Results copied to auxH show that I get numbers at least one order of magnitude bigger then expected or even weird numbers suggesting my operation is likely to overflow.
**Help**: what am I doing wrong? How can I make each thread to write and read each private location in global memory? Right now I'm debugging with `ARRDIM` = 512, but my goal is to make it work for `ARRDIM`~ 10^4, thus creating a `c_glob` array for 10^4*10^4 threads). I guess I will have issues with the total number of threads allowed per run.. So I was wondering if you could suggest any other solution to my problem.
Thank you.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cuPrintf.cu"
using namespace std;

#define ARRDIM 512
#define COLORLEVELS 4

__global__ void gpuKernel
(
    float *sa, float *aux,
    size_t memPitchAux, int w,
    float *c_glob
)
{
    float sc_loc[COLORLEVELS];

    float g0=0.0f;

    int tidx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; 
    int tidy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; 

    int idx  = tidy * memPitchAux/4 + tidx;

    for(int ic=0; ic<COLORLEVELS; ic++)
    {
        sc_loc[ic] = ((float)(ic*ic));
    }

    for(int is=0; is<COLORLEVELS; is++)
    {
        int ic = fabs(sa[tidy*w +tidx]);
        c_glob[tidy * COLORLEVELS + tidx + ic] += 1.0f;
    }

    for(int ic=0; ic<COLORLEVELS; ic++)
    {
        g0 += c_glob[tidy * COLORLEVELS + tidx + ic]*sc_loc[ic];
    }

    aux[idx] = g0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /*
     * array src host and device
     */
    int heightSrc = ARRDIM;
    int widthSrc = ARRDIM;
    cudaSetDevice(0);

    float *srcArr_h, *srcArr_d;
    size_t nBytesSrcArr = sizeof(float)*heightSrc * widthSrc;

    srcArr_h = (float *)malloc(nBytesSrcArr); // Allocate array on host
    cudaMalloc((void **) &srcArr_d, nBytesSrcArr); // Allocate array on device
    cudaMemset((void*)srcArr_d,0,nBytesSrcArr); // set to zero

    int totArrElm = heightSrc*widthSrc;

    for(int ic=0; ic<totArrElm; ic++)
    {
        srcArr_h[ic] = (float)(rand() % COLORLEVELS);
    }

    cudaMemcpy( srcArr_d, srcArr_h,nBytesSrcArr,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    /*
     * auxiliary buffer auxD to save final results
     */
    float *auxD;
    size_t auxDPitch;
    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&auxD,&auxDPitch,widthSrc*sizeof(float),heightSrc);
    cudaMemset2D(auxD, auxDPitch, 0, widthSrc*sizeof(float), heightSrc);

    /*
     * auxiliary buffer auxH allocation + initialization on host
     */
    size_t auxHPitch;
    auxHPitch = widthSrc*sizeof(float);
    float *auxH = (float *) malloc(heightSrc*auxHPitch);

    /*
     * kernel launch specs
     */
    int thpb_x = 16;
    int thpb_y = 16;

    int blpg_x = (int) widthSrc/thpb_x;
    int blpg_y = (int) heightSrc/thpb_y;
    int num_threads = blpg_x * thpb_x + blpg_y * thpb_y;

    /* 
     * c_glob: array that reserves a private location of COLORLEVELS floats for each thread
     */
    int cglob_w = COLORLEVELS;
    int cglob_h = num_threads;

    float *c_glob_d;
    size_t c_globDPitch;
    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&c_glob_d,&c_globDPitch,cglob_w*sizeof(float),cglob_h);
    cudaMemset2D(c_glob_d, c_globDPitch, 0, cglob_w*sizeof(float), cglob_h);

    /*
    * kernel launch
    */
    dim3 dimBlock(thpb_x,thpb_y, 1);
    dim3 dimGrid(blpg_x,blpg_y,1);

    gpuKernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(srcArr_d,auxD, auxDPitch, widthSrc, c_glob_d);

    cudaThreadSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy2D(auxH,auxHPitch, 
                 auxD,auxDPitch,  
                 auxHPitch, heightSrc,
                 cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();

    float min = auxH[0];
    float max = auxH[0];
    float f;
    string str;

    for(int i=0; i<widthSrc*heightSrc; i++)
    {

        if(min > auxH[i])
            min = auxH[i];
        if(max < auxH[i])
            max = auxH[i];
    }
    cudaFree(srcArr_d);
    cudaFree(auxD);
    cudaFree(c_glob_d);

}
```

Comment: my guess is you are doing no cuda error checking on your kernel, and it's not running correctly.  what happens when you run the code with `cuda-memcheck` ?

Comment: Would it be possible to post a full compilable and executable code reproducing your error?

Comment: voting to close.  SO expects: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "  You haven't provided a SSCCE.org code

Comment: sorry for losing your time but the problem is that all threads try to update the same array on gmem,that is why I get mad results.The fact is that my original kernel has much more code in it,and if I alloc+init c[] in the kernel (c[] stored in the registers/local mem),the run fails with _gpuContrastKernel() execution failed:(6) the launch timed out and was terminated_This happens using a Tesla M2090 cluster,but if I run the code on my workstation(TESLA C1060) my implementation goes just fine.I read Fermi architecture is much more strict,could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You decided neither not to show the whole code nor a reduced size thereof reproducing your problem. Therefore, it has not been possible to make tests and verify the possible solution below.

I think you have spot the source of the problem: multiple threads are trying to write to the same memory locations in parallel. This is a situation leading to race conditions. For an example, see the fourth slide of the presentation ["CUDA C: race conditions, atomics, locks, mutex, and warps"](http://will-landau.com/gpu/lectures/cudac-atomics/cudac-atomics.pdf).

Race conditions have a brute-force solution: atomic functions. They are described at Section B.12 of the CUDA C Programming Guide. So you can try to fix your problem by changing the line

```
c[ic] += 1.0f;
```

to

```
atomicAdd(&c[ic],1);
```

You will pay this fix with performance: atomic operations serialize the code to avoid race conditions.

I have mentioned that atomic functions are a brute-force solution to your problem because it can be that, by properly rethinking the implementation, you can find a way to avoid them. But this is not possible to say as of now due to the very few details you provided.

Comment: okay, thank you. I posted a code reproducing the problem. Hope now my issue is clearer. Atomic operations unfortunately are not helpful in my situation, now that I shared the code should be clear.